# Label Text Change on Every Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I want to change my label on button click, say i have 5 questions, which i need to display on every button "Next" click.
I have tried this, but on every click, it displays the first one("xxxxxx") only.

```
int i = 0;    
string[] Question = { "xxxxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz" , "ddddddd" , "dddcc" };            
Changetext.Text = Question[i];
i++;
```

Comment: Please describe your problem

Comment: In ASP.NET all variables and controls are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. You need to persist this value somewhere. For example in Session, ViewState or in a HiddenField.

Comment: @ChristophKn: doesn't change anything, see my last comment

Comment: Ok, let me try that
Thanks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but the text is stored in the viewstate of the control, which can be used

Comment: @fubo: but he wants to store the current index, on every button click it should advance to the next position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should do it

```
string[] Question = { "xxxxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz", "ddddddd", "dddcc" };
int i = Array.IndexOf(Question, Changetext.Text);
if(i >= 0 && i < 4)
{
    Changetext.Text = Question[i+1];
}
else
{
    Changetext.Text = Question[0];
}
```

you search the text of your current question in the question array, if it exists you select the next, if not you select the first

Answer (score -1):

Try to in Asp.net:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
ViewState["i"] = 0;
}

string[] Question = { "xxxxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz" , "ddddddd" , "dddcc" };            
Changetext.Text = Question[int.Parse(ViewState["i"].ToString()];
int inc = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["i"]) + 1;
ViewState["i"] = inc;
```